# JavaScript image toggling click

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I working on image toggling, first click should hide the image and second click should display the image again. I got some thing working, but the issue is, on first click it is doing nothing and on second click toggling gets started. Hope there is some thing wrong in my code. Please advise.

```
<img src="img/1.jpg" width="449" height="600" class="one" id="one" style="opacity=1">
<img src="img/2.jpg" width="450" height="600" class="two">

function toggle(obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById("one");
    
    if ( el.style.opacity != 0 ) {
        el.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    else {
        el.style.opacity = 1;
    }
}

one.addEventListener("click", toggle, false);
```

Comment: Using opacity to show hide elements? Why not just use visibility?

Comment: @epascarello when the element is invisible you can't click it again.

Answer (score 6):

`style="opacity=1"` should be `style="opacity:1"`.  The rule, as you've written it, is invalid and will be ignored, so the first click on the element will set the opacity to 1 (which is the default anyway).

nb, you could refactor your function to look like this:

```
function toggle(obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById("one");

    el.style.opacity = +!+el.style.opacity;
    // or, using bitwise XOR assignment to keep @Raynos happy
    // el.style.opacity ^= 1;
}
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/se29y/**

This converts the current value from a string, e.g. `"1"` to a number, e.g. `1`, then negates the "truthiness" of that number, `!1 === false`, then converts the resulting boolean back to a number again before it is assigned to `opacity`.  This means each click toggles the value to its opposite.

Of course, as [@casablanca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4452023/javascript-toggling/4452063#4452063) points out, `visibility` is more appropriate (and more widely supported) for in-place hiding of elements, but a hidden element cannot be clicked to be shown again (thanks @Shadow Wizard).

Comment: @Raynos: no! JSLint will hurt my feelings if I do.

Comment: visibility is more appropriate but as the requirement is clicking the element itself it can't be used: hidden element can't be clicked, I just checked it out now.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: that's something I was unsure of myself.  Thanks for clarifying and doing something that I was far, far too lazy to do myself.

Comment: sure, guess that's the reason the OP here used opacity in the first place. :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `opacity` to show/hide elements -- use `visibility` instead with the values `visible` or `hidden`.

Comment: Argh, I was just typing this :)

Comment: Or `display: none` if you want to completely remove it from the DOM. Otherwise other elements will still move aside for the hidden element.

Answer (score 1):

```
function toggle(obj) {
    var el = document.getElementById("one");

    el.style.opacity = el.style.opacity^1;
}
```

Because converting to integer twice in a single expression is stupid.

Comment: Douglas Crockford is going to show up at your house unannounced, and beat you to death with a sign that says *'Problem at line 4 character 40: Unexpected use of '^'.'*

Comment: @AndyE Pedantic people use a logical negation and two arithmetic addition to EMULATE a binary XOR just to satisfy crockford

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately and unsurprisingly, each browser has its own implementation of opacity.. so here is cross browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox) version of the original code:

```
function Toggle(element) {
    var curOpacity;
    if (typeof element.style.filter != "undefined") {
        curOpacity = parseInt(element.style.filter.split("=")[1]);
        if (isNaN(curOpacity))
            curOpacity = 100;
        element.style.filter = "alpha (opacity=" + (100 - curOpacity) + ")";
    }
    else {
        curOpacity = element.style.opacity || 1;
        element.style.opacity = +!+curOpacity;
    }
}
```

To apply this on all images at page load:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
        images[i].onclick = function() { Toggle(this); };
}
```

Working test case with cute cats: http://jsfiddle.net/2sXVQ/2/  :)